# How are RF filters constructed?

Tags: rf, filter, high-frequency, parasitic-capacitance, pcb-simulation

I want to know what filter circuits look like in the RF (MHz-GHz) frequency range. Are they just like low frequency LC filters, but with appropriately adjusted component values?

For example the VLF-80+ from minicircuits. Why are they so expensive, at around $30 per part? I know that they are high order filters, but still $30 sounds too expensive for a simple LC filter.

I ask this because I tried to design a 200 MHz bandpass filter myself.

I ordered a PCB from JLCPCB but the filter doesn't work at all. It's not easy to identify the problem because I don't have a high frequency network analyzer. I can't even measure the components because my multimeter can't measure capacitances that are less than 100 pF.

Here's my 5th order, 50 Ω output filter.

[image]

And here's the PCB layout. I know it's not good enough. I just started designing PCBs.
[image]

Comment: If you can't measure it, how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: _"doesn't work at all"_ Please explain expected versus observed behavior.

Comment: Sorry I should've included more information. For now the way I test it is I use a VCO to create the input signal. VCO can scan between 140 Mhz and 300 Mhz.  I monitor the output using a 1.5 GHz spectrum analyzer. I cannot see the time signal I can only see frequency vs power graph. I know the filter doesnt work because when I connect the filter to the VCO output, I can't see anything on the spectrum analyzer.

Comment: @MustafaTurhan Do you have controlled-impedance traces on your board? Are you using appropriate capacitors and inductors (at these frequencies, you need C0G capacitors and air-core inductors)?

Comment: Oh, if you scan the VCO, how do you synchronize your spectrum analyzer to that scan? Otherwise, you won't get meaningful measurements: It would fully depend on when the SA "looks" at your oscilator.

Comment: @Hearth I don't have controlled impedance traces. I just made the traces wider and thought it would be enough.  I used ceramic SMD capacitors and inductors.  That's the problem. I didn't know that I have to use controlled-impedance traces and air-core inductors etc. I want to design it the proper way but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I scan it with a very low frequency like 1 Hz. I doesn't need to be synchronized. I observe that 9 dbm input signal reduces to -20 dbm in the passband which shouldn't happen.

Comment: @MustafaTurhan At these capacitances, most ceramic SMD capacitors are going to be C0G or maybe U2J, which is almost as good. It's the inductors that are the problem, and the trace impedance. Anything above about 50 MHz or so is basically going to require air-core inductors, as ferrite and iron cores become very lossy (there might be a handful of ferrite formulations that can still be used, but i wouldn't recommend it). You also *absolutely* need controlled impedance traces; right now, the impedance mismatch is going to be reflecting much or most of your power back to the source.

Comment: When working at this sort of frequency, it's usual to wind your own air-core inductors, incidentally. I suggest you get a good LCR meter with measurement frequencies of at least 100 kHz, preferably 1 MHz, or even better, a network analyzer. Then get yourself some sufficiently stiff magnet wire (#16 AWG is a good balance, though #18 and even #20 would work) and something to use as a mandrel (I use the handle of an x-acto knife, a sharpie, and a ¾" wooden dowel for three different sizes), wind some inductors, and measure and tweak as necessary.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks for your help. Can I wind an inductor in the range of 1n-200nH. And Is it possible to achieve an exact value like 5.6 nH?

Comment: @MustafaTurhan Yes, you certainly can. To get an exact value, you can spread out the windings to reduce their coupling, which lowers the inductance in a smooth continuous fashion. I recommend putting the inductors in-circuit and then tweaking them while monitoring how the response changes; that tends to work better than just using calculated values, as it automatically compensates for parasitic elements. It's very manual, though. You may start to see why the mini-circuits parts cost so much.

Comment: @MustafaTurhan [This is why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyu8z.jpg) they can be very expensive! ([See bottom of this page](https://nuwaves.com/using-time-to-save-time-tuning-filters/) to find that image.)

Comment: Also, please show your layout.

Comment: I don't think anyone has mentioned this yet, but you may be interested in Kuroda's identities and [commensurate line circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurate_line_circuit).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you've discovered, once you are up in the 100MHz+ range, little is "simple".

When using discrete capacitors and inductors, you have to consider their parasitic complements. Even basic connecting elements such as traces have to have their characteristics carefully considered, because they too have capacitance, inductance, impedance and skin effects.

It *can* all be mastered (and there are lots of good texts on practical RF design), but whilst it is simple to model such filters with ideal components, the physical reality is much more complex...

At 80m/3.5MHz filters are still built with discrete components and ferrite cored inductors. (See [this](http://arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/9809qex057.pdf) ARRL 80m design.)

[image]

This [link](https://reflector.sota.org.uk/t/2m-bandpass-filter-repair/25526) shows the inside of a practical DIY 2m / 150MHz bandpass filter, with screw mount piston adjustable capacitors and hand formed air-cored inductors.  The adjustable caps are critical, because you need to compensate for the hard to predict stray capacitances. The inductors are air cored due to high ferrite losses, and low target inductance.

[image]

Professionally designed/built filters in the GHz range will typically use transmission line designs created with CAD software which can do EM analysis.  You will rarely see discrete components, just oddly bent traces and stubs, but they can work wonderfully.

Have a look [here](https://surface.syr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=eecs_thesis) for an example of a 3GHz-11GHz bandpass filter from a master's thesis.

[image]

And the resulting performance.

[image]

In your case, you'd want to make sure you are using air cored inductors, and that you allow for stray/parasitic capacitances.

A discrete design built in a metal box like the 2m example, might be your best approach in terms of ability to experiment. In fact you could just adapt the example circuit for your use by tweaking the values

Comment: Okay it's not so simple. Then how should I proceed to design the filter. Do I need to do Ansys simulations? How should I test the components? I graduated only a year ago and I always wonder how a experienced engineer design circuits. I always take the easiest route. I know that things are not so simple but I don't know other more advanced ways. For the RF filter, I calculated the component values from an online LC filter design tool. I designed the pcb from KiCAD and ordered it in Jlcpcb.  But now it doesnt work.

Comment: "Then how should I proceed to design the filter" -- If that is your actual question, then start a new submission and ask your actual question.

Comment: @DavideAndrea If is ask that then people tell me go use google or whatever.

Comment: If you are starting RF design from scratch, then personally I'd recommend a copy of the ARRL handbook http://arrl.org/arrl-handbook-2023. Second hand copies are cheap, and anything dated in the last 20 years will deliver on both analog and digital circuits (from time to time I still reference my 1988 copy).  Critically, they contain lots of the practical details which more theoretical texts often ignore.

Comment: I've added examples of filters in various frequency ranges to give you a feel for the way practical constructions vary. Hope it helps, but do look at ARRL handbook for more guidance.

Comment: @MustafaTurhan Consider that the final example in this answer is a master's thesis project from 2013 (the answer says doctoral thesis, but that's an error.) I think any question for which the answer is an entire university thesis is probably too broad to ask here. (And that thesis is just one filter; the question of "how do I design RF filters in general" is much bigger.) I don't know if 200 MHz is low enough (or 2013 is long-enough ago) that the answer is more straightforward / better understood.

Comment: I'll correct the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MustafaTurhan If the above answers your question, then please mark as Answered to help others looking for similar guidance.

Comment: @colintd Thank you! This is very helpful. I will study book and learn more about the theory before desiging again.

Answer (score 2):

The challenge when realizing filters for high frequencies comes from two main issues: parasitic elements and component tolerance. These two factors work against you as the frequencies get higher: the L and C values get smaller, so these deviations have greater influence on your filter.

Why are the commercial ones so expensive then? They’re made with premium materials and use higher-stability, lower-parasitic components. In addition, they are tuned in manufacturing to their target specification.

There are also economics to consider. Filters that have a high-volume use (like diplexers for cable modems and set-top boxes) can be remarkably cheap for the performance they deliver, because their development and tooling can be spread out over a wide number of units. As an example, typical cable TV diplexers have PC boards in a can, use air-core inductors and polyester or mica caps, and sell for a few dollars in volume.

Specialty filters with lower running volumes will cost more as their upfront investments need to be recovered over fewer units. Inevitably, if there isn’t competition then prices will be even higher, because reasons.

Comment: A much simpler explanation for cost suffices: Minicircuits and etc. are in the small quantity specialty market; they charge whatever people are willing to pay. Low quantity may mean higher production cost as well (though I suspect given the simplicity of many of their products, most of that either covers engineering cost, or sweet sweet profit margin).

Answer (score 1):

I simulated your filter and it looks good. You need to buy affordable [NanoVNA](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004745862162.html) to check where the problem is.

[image]

Comment: The challenge in physical implementation (as opposed to simulation) relates to stray capacitances, the use of ferrite inductors (which will tend to be very lossy at 200MHz), and trace impedance mis-match.

Be interesting to try adding a few pF stray capacitance in multiple places down to ground (and across the inductors), and some resistors in series with the inductors to match their loss characteristics.

Comment: This simulation doesn't take any parasitics into consideration, though. The "You need to buy X" makes me almost think this is some kind of sophisticated spam....